# NullReferenceException when doing InsertOnSubmit in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, nullreferenceexception, insertonsubmit

In my database I have a table called
StaffMembers

when I bring this into my .net Project as through linq-to-sql an entity class StaffMember is created

Now I have also created a partial class StaffMember in my project also, to add extra properties that I use in other top layers. eg. IsDeleted property. This partial class also inherits an abstract class and interface to make sure some other properties are also implemented.

Now when I create a new instance of "StaffMember"

eg.
StaffMember newStaff = new StaffMember();
and give it all its properties etc

and then call the InsertOnSubmit on the context through my Manager.

```
Add(StaffMember newStaff)
{
     context.StaffMembers.InsertOnSubmit(newStaff);
     context.Save();
}
```

I get an
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

on   context.StaffMembers.InsertOnSubmit(newStaff);

The stack says

```
"   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.EntitySetDefSourceAccessor`2.GetValue(T instance)\r\n   at 
System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaAccessor`2.GetBoxedValue(Object instance)\r\n   at 
System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.StandardTrackedObject.HasDeferredLoader(MetaDataMember deferredMember)\r\n   at 
System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.StandardTrackedObject.get_HasDeferredLoaders()\r\n   at 
System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.Track(MetaType mt, Object obj, Dictionary`2 visited, Boolean recurse, Int32 level)\r\n   at 
System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.Track(Object obj, Boolean recurse)\r\n   at 
System.Data.Linq.ChangeTracker.StandardChangeTracker.Track(Object obj)\r\n   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.InsertOnSubmit(TEntity entity)\r\n   at 
BusinessObjects.StaffMemberManager.Add(StaffMember staffMember) in     
C:\\StaffMemberManager.cs:line 251"
```

Any idea why would this be happening and what's the way around it.

Thanks

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Alright I found my answer on
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/0cf1fccb-6398-4f16-920b-adef9dc4ac9f

in case some is still looking for an answer.

This problem happens when you overload the constructor in the partial class, and not call the default constructor in it.

The default constructor of the entity does few things thats required by the Context object.

Hence if you have an overloading constructor in your partial class and using it to create the object, make sure the default constructor is called in the first line

in C# you can do this by

eg.

```
 Customer(string custID)
```

you need to add a

```
 Customer(string custID):this()
```

in C# where Customer is my class and Customer(string custID):this() is my overload constructor in my partial class.

Comment: Dude, you just saved me a LOT of time. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: And for me that didnt help.

Comment: @AgentFire - me neither - you find your problem ?

Comment: @AgentFire - the issue ended up being related to multithreading - i messed something up concurrently calling InsertOnSubmit ... I'm not sure exactly the details of why - maybe the object-tracking isn't thread safe, but processing on a single thread fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm getting this.  Instead of extending the LINQ class I am subclassing it. in my new class I have the constructor as: public NewClass() : base() { }, so I think it calls the base class  constructor, but I still get the error.  I will copy to new instances of the base class and then insert on submit, but I think my method should also work.  I don't need the extended properties in the database, they are just for user information.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime, just forgot to add this line to the base class:

[InheritanceMapping(Code = "Class", Type = typeof(Class))]